# Could this date refer to a divorce on the 1939 register?

Tags: census-records, 1930s, wiltshire, divorce-records

Here is the time line for my grandmother:

[image]

I know that she got divorced from my late grandfather sometime after I was born. So 1972 is a guess.

But I noticed this additional information of the 1939 Register:

[image]

Next to **Manor Farm Cottage** it has extra writing:

> CR283 19-10-76 WL

I don't know what this reference means. I wondered if this was the date of her divorce? I come to this assumption because her surname was also crossed out and her maiden surname of Weeks inserted.

---

### Update

I stumbled over the [Lost Cousins 1939 Register Special Newsletter](https://www.lostcousins.com/newsletters2/1939special.htm) where it states towards the bottom:

> **CR283** is a form that is used when there is a **Change of Surname**, Forename, or Date of Birth (most changes will be surname changes, of course).

So either this date is when the event happened, or it is the date that the change was document. Eitherway, her divorce must have been around this date. Or is it **the** actual date?

---

## Update

I now notice this in the same linked article, albeit about marriage changes:

> This means that where a date is shown all you can conclude is that the event must have happened prior ...

Comment: 19-10-76 looks like a date, and WL looks like the county code for Wiltshire, but that's not enough for an answer. You may have to write (or visit, if you're nearby) the Wilts county offices.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All that you can be certain of is that she changed her surname to Weeks and notified the change which was recorded on that date. She may or may not have divorced Frederick, she could just have notified a name change for a multitude of reasons not just divorce. For example: Did she marry a man with the surname of Weeks? If so the divorce could have happened some time before the marriage and the notification.

Comment: Weeks is her maiden surname. I know that for fact. And I did visit my Nan a few times and my mum has always said they divorced.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle I have cases in my research where both bride and groom have the same surname.  Colin is correct.  It may be more likely that she returned to the use of her maiden name, but I wouldn't rule out the possibility that she married someone else named Weeks.  It does happen.

Comment: @JanMurphy We don't have to guess here. This is my Grandmother. I know she married my Granddad (becoming Truckle) and divorced (returning to Weeks). She died single - fact. I simply was hoping to establish the date of her divorce without paying lots of money  - since it doesn't really matter. But she did not marry again. I know personally ...

Answer (score 5):

CR283 is the form used for a change of name on marriage. A change of name for any other reason should be CR230. So this appears to be at variance with family information, although there is always the possibility that someone used the wrong form, or the NHS Central Register clerk made a clerical error.